# How to fix overflow in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

here is my app

[image]

as you can see working well, I installed this on my phone, and it works fine too.
and I send this to my friend, and his phone showing like this

[image]

mine and his phone is same phone, literally same phone, but in his and any others phone is showing this overflow, mine and this emulator have no problem, how do i fix overflow problem

```
class Homescreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const Homescreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Pluto Guess Game"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white60,
        ),
        body: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: SafeArea(
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                Card(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      PlayerWidget(
                        player: messi
                      ),
                      PlayerWidget(
                        player: neymar
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Card(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      PlayerWidget(
                        player: mbappe
                      )
                      PlayerWidget(
                        player: ramos
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Card(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                       PlayerWidget(
                        player: messi
                      ),
                      PlayerWidget(
                        player: neymar
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Card(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                       PlayerWidget(
                        player: messi
                      ),
                      PlayerWidget(
                        player: neymar
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Card(
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.gesture),
                    iconSize: 50,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    splashColor: Colors.orange,
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (nav) {
                            return const Asking();
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and also I'm new at flutter, I know I'm doing lot of mistake in this code please suggest that also

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Comment: Can you share code

Comment: You can use the Expanded widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

->Use This Code

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double h =  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double w =  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(

      appBar: getAppBar(context, "Back", "", []),
      body: SafeArea(
        top: true,
        bottom: true,
        child: Column(
          children: [


            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: 15,
                  itemBuilder: (context,v){
                return
                     Container(
                       padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0,right: 15.0),
                       child: Column(
                         children: [
                           Row(
                             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                             children: [
                               Container(
                                 height: h*0.2,
                                 width: w*0.4,
                                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                   color: Colors.red,
                                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0)
                                 ),
                                
                               ),
                               Container(
                                 height: h*0.2,
                                 width: w*0.4,
                                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                     color: Colors.black38,
                                     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0)
                                 ),
                               ),

                             ],
                           ),
                           SizedBox(height: 15.0,),
                           Divider(

                             color: Colors.black,
                           ),
                           SizedBox(height: 15.0,),
                         ],
                       ),
                     );
              }),
            )

            

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: `->Use This Code` good answers try to teach people _why_ a solution works, or what went wrong, etc. if you just say - "do this" and never tell people what they did wrong, then they don't learn

Comment: you share code This File

Comment: here is my code : https://pastebin.com/8BGnKTtj

Answer (score 0):

Without your code I can't make corrections to the current code. but if you need responsive UI that work regardless of screen size, I suggest you use Rows, Columns with Expanded Widget, as necessary.

for example if you need to have 2 Items inside a Row where each occupies same space you can use,

```
Row (
children: [
    Expanded (
      flex:1
      child: YourWidget()
    ),
    Expanded (
      flex:1
      child: YourWidget()
    )
  ]
)
```

Remember to remove hardcoded size properties along the main axis of your Colum or Row.

Same goes for Columns.

If you need each to have varied sizes, you can use flex property of the Expanded Widget. for example, one items has 1/3 of width and other has 2/3 you can put 1 and 2 as flex values.

more explanation from flutter team: [Expanded](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rnZaagadyo)

Comment: i also used the row, but it didn't, here is my code : https://pastebin.com/8BGnKTtj

Comment: @mishalhaneef I can see you have used a fixed value as width for images.  remove that but keep the height.

Comment: also usage of extreme padding could also contributed to the problem you have

Comment: thankyou @Srila Sachintha. it worked